# Is there a HTML/JS game engine/library that deals with things (HUD, menus, accounts, etc) other than the core gameplay?

Tags: javascript, html5, web

I've been looking through the many HTML/Javascript game engines/libraries out there (many of which are found here https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines).  Most of them seem fairly focussed on the actual gameplay components: sounds, sprites & graphics management, doing 2D and 3D animations, collision detection, etc.

From what I can see most of them lack things to handle all the other stuff that goes into a web game such as menus, HUD, workflows of all the various scenes, management of various points/achievements and understanding of how level progression works with that, integration with Facebook or other external accounts, etc.

Does anything exist that adresses these sorts of pieces?  I realize none of them are that difficult to achieve on their own but it would seem to be somewhat distracting overhead that gets in the way of the main game development focus, and is usually very similar from game to game.

Additional question: would something like this be useful, would you want/use it?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the functions you're asking about are handled by third party libraries (achiements, integration with Facebook, etc), or can simply be handled with jQuery and basic HTML and Javascript code (menus, HUD, etc). Or, they are things that come about as part of creating the game itself, and as such, aren't part of a standard library functionality (level progression, or workflow of scenes).

Additionally, all games are somewhat different, so most libraries usually only handle the major gameplay components. Handling more than that would result in a library designed for a very specific type of game, and while that's possible, it's less useful than a more generic library.

Answer (score 1):

check http://cocos2d-javascript.org/

Its not completed yet and I am looking forward for this awesome framework to get completed. cocos2d have features to easily create menus, manage screen flows, apart from regular gameplay support. But for handling scoring, level data, facebook/twitter, I you need to go for your own implementation/respective libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always using [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) both for games and regular webapplications and the Views it offers might just be what you are searching for.